# PostGIS ordering overlapping polygons

Tags: geospatial, postgis, topology

Is there a way in PostGIS to order polygons in layers such that when they overlap at a particular x,y point, where I’m looking for intersecting polygons, I can find the one that’s on the top? I am not looking to flatten / cut this data as being able to identify all intersections at a given point is also valuable.

Comment: The question is mixing a display issue (not related to postgis) and a computational one. For the later, to find all intersections at a given location, use st_intersects between the layer and the point of interest.

Comment: Which part of the question are you identifying as a “display issue” @JGH?

Comment: The concept of "ordering polygon to find the one on top" sounds like a display challenge. It does not matter in the DB if row A is stored/returned before/after row B, their order is irrelevant.

Comment: @JGH the order is relevant and it’s not actually as easy of a problem to solve as it initially seems. When you have enough overlapping shapes and different ordering between them it actually becomes a graph. I do know how to solve the graph problem, but I was hoping instead that there was built-in functionality that can simplify this in PostGIS so I’m not finding all intersecting layers then doing a topological sort on a DAG to figure out their order. Meanwhile this means I’m also maintaining a series of graphs and a bunch of related operations to ensure certain constraints aren’t violated.